# Ionic2 - Download de Imagens e Salvar na Galeria

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic2, angular

Galera, duvida simples para vocês

Como faço o download de uma imagem que estar num sevidor e em seguida, salvar elas na Galeria do device (IOS e Android).

PS: estou usando ionic 2

Desde já agradeço a todos

Comment: VC já consegue recuperar a imagem desse servidor?

Comment: Sim. Eu as salvei em outra rotina! Tenho a URL dela. mais preciso baixa-la pra meu dispositivo. Como faço?

Comment: https://github.com/dsgriffin/ionic-2-file-transfer-example/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts

Comment: Mas antes de usar o exemplo que lhe passei talvez seja necessário converter a imagem pra base64, aqui tem uma resposta que pode te ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890177/ionic2-load-and-save-image-to-device-using-cordova-file-transfer

Comment: Vou dar uma analisada, mais Agradeço bastante desde já!

Comment: Por nada, caso não consiga posso te ajudar mais detalhadamente

Comment: Pois é. Não to conseguindo. me add no hangout: luizdantasdesign@gmail.com

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51708/discussion-between-luiz-felipe-and-diegoaugusto).

Comment: Não sei se a mensagem anterior chegou, mais não consegui!